# Ordering multiple IonicModals on top of each other

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, ionic-framework

The usage of the $ionicModal service is explained here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/

I have a situation where it happens that I open more than two modals.

For example:

1. I first open a `loginModal`
2. In there, user clicks on a button "openSignUp()" which opens the `SignUpModal`

However, somethimes it happens that the signup modal is opened below the login modal. So I have to close login before I can see it.

Is there a way to either
 - push the new modal to the top
 - or to order the modals?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When modals are opened they are appended to DOM. So remember which ever modal you open `first`, that will be `appended to DOM first`.

Also, all modals have same css `z-index:10`.

To understand this why this overlap happens.

1. `Modal1` is opened -> Gets appended to DOM `<body>` TAG.
2. `Modal2` is opened -> Gets appended to DOM `<body>` TAG after Modal1's
   `<div>` Tag.
3. `Modal3` is opened -> Gets appended to DOM `<body>` TAG after Modal2's
   `<div>` Tag.

**Bug condition**: If you have a button on `Modal3` to open `Modal2 or Modal1`

The `Modal1` or `Modal2` will open behind the Modal3.

**WORKAROUND:** You need to manipulate the `z-index` of each modal so that in whatever order they are opened,the last modal you click should/will open over previously opened modal.

I cant provided you with a quick solution, because its not a quick fix;however I did solve it by reading the source Code and editing it.

Here is how I fixed my problem: A [Pull Request](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/pull/4121) to Ionic repo.
You can easily read the changes done there in order to have a fix. Its all basically manipulation of `z-index`

Comment: Great reflection. But if you know the order in advance, will it also work by setting a custom css (e.g. modal1css etc) and within a z-index value?

Comment: Yes if you know the order of modals beforehand then you can manually set the z-index(s). I hope ionic team fixes this issue soon.

Comment: Tried it with style="z-index: 100 !important;" but it didnt work.

Comment: You need to add that to <div> with class="backdrop". Its the backdrop that has the index. Don't the modal itself.

Answer (score 15):

This is what I did to workaround this problem:

First, define a css style for a class name

```
.top-modal {
    z-index: 11;
}
```

Then modify the modal's class name by adding in `top-modal` during initialization

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('myTopModal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-left'
})
.then(function (modal) {
    modal.el.className = modal.el.className + " top-modal";
    $scope.myTopModal = modal;
});
```

Comment: This is also possible (instead of defining a css class): modal.el.style.zIndex = 11;

Comment: very awesome answer!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to append and remove the modal from the DOM each time the modal is opened and closed respectively. This way the modal will always be the last one appended to the DOM when it is opened.

Here is the code I've been using:

```
     // Open the login loginModal
    $scope.openLoginModal = function() {
        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
            scope: $scope
        }).then(function(loginModal) {
            $scope.loginModal = loginModal;

            // Show modal once it's finished loading
            $scope.loginModal.show();
        });
    };

    // Close login modal
    $scope.closeLogin = function() {
        $scope.loginModal.hide();

        // Remove login modal from the DOM
        $scope.loginModal.remove();
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve by hiding the modal you don't want to be on top, for example:

```
function showSignupModal() {
   if ($scope.loginModal.isShown())
      $scope.loginModal.hide();
   $scope.signUpModal.show();
}
```

However, if you want to keep the loginModal open in background for some reason, you can open and close the loginModal beforehand this way:

```
function showSignupModal() {
   if (!$scope.loginModal.isShown())
      $scope.loginModal.show();
      $scope.loginModal.hide();
   }
   $scope.signUpModal.show();
 }
```