# ionic modal opens behind another modal

Tags: ionic-framework

In my main ionic view I have a category modal that can be called by clicking a button and this modal contains a list of categories that can be selected by user.
Then I have another modal that contains a form and my category modal can also be called from this form modal by clicking another button.

If I directly open the form modal and call the category modal from there, everything works just fine and I can view the category modal.
but the problem is if I first call the category modal and close it and then open the form modal and call the category modal from there, it will open behind the form modal and I have to close the form modal to see the category modal.

how can I fix that?
thanks.

Comment: I think you should provide some code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer this answer for your scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31629855/3878940 It explains similar scenario when multiple modals are opened and how they overlap with each other